# What to do with feature button in an app when user permanently rejects the runtime permission for it?

Tags: usability, android, permissions

The permission model in Android allows a user to either grant, deny, or permanently deny a runtime permission.  Also if the user denies a permission twice it is treated as a permanently deny.

I have a button for a feature that requires the permission.  What do I do with it if the user has permanently denied the permission?

Showing a message on click that says: "To use this feature please uninstall the app, and reinstall it, and grant permission x when prompted" seems kind of terrible, but so does two different people having a radically different feature set based on a runtime permission.

This is a somewhat similar question to [Show/hide actions when the user doesn't have permission](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/108754/show-hide-actions-when-the-user-doesnt-have-permission) except that if the user permanently denies the permission, there is no way to undo that other than reinstalling the app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The situation is not ideal, and there's no elegant way out -- but you don't need to direct your users to reinstall the app either. You can send them to the settings panel for your application, where permissions are managed, and they can revise their decision.

After detecting this is the case, you might show a dialog (to create the expectation), then automatically navigate to the relevant settings when the user confirms.

There are examples of this if you look around. Try going to the settings panel for some of your installed apps and permanently revoking permissions, see how they handle it.

The code for this is relatively simple. Again, it's not exactly elegant, but beats reinstalling by a wide margin.